# Get the updated database records automatically by a windows form application using c#

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows software and i have a database. So what i want is , if the database records are updated my windows application should detect it automatically and retrieve those updated records. can anybody provide a solution for this?

Comment: you'd have to run a background task to poll the database for new rows. Don't run it too often or you'll overload the server or could even accidentally lock your tables. Unless your DBMS has the capability to emit events or something. Your question is too vague for SO though really.

Comment: Thanks.... I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Check SqlDependency Class

in Sql:

```
ALTER DATABASE SampleDB SET SINGLE_USER;

ALTER DATABASE SampleDB SET ENABLE_BROKER;

ALTER DATABASE SampleDB SET MULTI_USER;

CREATE QUEUE myTableMessages;

CREATE SERVICE myTableNotifications ON QUEUE myTableMessages("http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification");
```

////

in visual:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace NotifyService
{
public class SqlNotifier : IDisposable
{
    public SqlCommand SqlCmd { get; set; }
    public SqlConnection SqlCon { get; set; }


    public void StartMonitoring()
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(this.SqlCon.ConnectionString);
        RegisterDependency();
    }


    private event EventHandler<SqlNotificationEventArgs> _NewNotification;
    public event  EventHandler<SqlNotificationEventArgs> NewNotification
    {
        add { this._NewNotification += value; }
        remove { this._NewNotification -= value; }
    }


    public virtual void OnNewNotification(SqlNotificationEventArgs notification)
    {  
        if (this._NewNotification != null)
            this._NewNotification(this, notification);
    }


    public void RegisterDependency()
    {
        this.SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SqlCmd.CommandText,this.SqlCon);
        this.SqlCmd.Notification = null;


        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(this.SqlCmd);
        dependency.OnChange += this.Dependency_OnChange;


        if (this.SqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            this.SqlCon.Open();


        this.SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        this.SqlCon.Close();
    }


    private void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
        dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(Dependency_OnChange);
        this.OnNewNotification(e);
        RegisterDependency();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(this.SqlCon.ConnectionString);
    }


}
}
```

///
Use:

```
using NotifyService;
private SqlNotifier NS = new SqlNotifier();
NS.SqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***");
NS.SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, name FROM dbo.mytable");
NS.StartMonitoring();
NS.NewNotification += new EventHandler<SqlNotificationEventArgs>(DependencyEventHandler);
```

Comment: this is very detailed...but the question doesn't even specify whether the database is SQL Server or not. Would make sense to check that assumption first. Also I think this much code merits a proper explanation of what it is and how it works. From a brief read I can see how the C# monitors the database, but as someone who's never seen this before it's not obvious how data gets into the notifications queue in the first place. Perhaps linking to documentation etc would also help people with the concepts.